# Is it true that a server is usually much better protected against Infection by Website Malicious Code?

Tags: networking, security

I heard this statement:

> The security of the server is usually much higher than that of a normal PC. Generally, it is impossible to implant a bot through Infection, Website Malicious Code, etc.

Can someone explain this statement?
Is it because the server OS is different?

Comment: where did you see this quote?

Comment: I heard from a security commissioner.

Comment: Sounds like complete lies. Also, the heck is "webpage hanging"?

Comment: it's `Website Malicious Code`.

Comment: That statement is garbage (demonstrably false). How does the maker of the statement think maicious code gets into websites without getting onto the server. Ignoring stuff used by the best of the best hackers (eg firmware backdoors, rowhammer attacks) a server and desktop will have the same vulnerabilities if they run the same software.

Comment: In fact I think you wil find most bot infections come through compromised servers - indeed one common pattern I see regularly is : phishing emails directing people to a compromised website where they need to download software/enter password to fix a non existent account problem. Note that its the websites SITTING ON SERVERS that hold the source of infection.

Comment: It would be fair to say that often these servers are complicit in the process but are not themselves running the infection - but this has nithing to do with their security, rather with the profole if attacks, which often require user action when the malware users specofically want lack of action from comprpmised servers (as action would lead to loss of use of server for further exploit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Impossible" is a big word and inappropriate.

What this means is probably that a pure server has no users that are surfing the web
on unsafe websites, or download doubtful software or receive
phishing emails and carelessly click bait links.

In that respect, without the human factor, a server would be much safer,
but far from safe. Nothing that is connected to the Internet can be said
to be safe.